# Citrus Framework - Validate JSON response with Java DSL

Tags: json, validation, response, citrus-framework

I have checked the Citrus documentation, but I could not find an example.
My code is in the following style:

```
   http()
        .client(something)
        .receive()
        .response(HttpStatus.OK)
        .messageType(MessageType.JSON);
```

How can I check a token in the JSON response, that it contains only numbers and letters for instance with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JsonPath expressions in combination with RegExp validation matchers.

```
http()
    .client(something)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate("$.user.name", "Penny")
    .validate("$.user.aliases", "@matches('[a-z0-9]')@");
```

Also see documentation here

http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/json-path.html
http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/validation-matchers.html